# Crash when assigning value

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsdictionary, downcast

Analytics show 5 users have had 20 crashes when the following method runs. Backend made a change that now returns an array containing a single dictionary. I quickly added this code to cover both cases. What about this code could be causing crashing very inconsistently, since I or none of the testers have been able to reproduce?

```
+ (instancetype)createOrUpdateObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSDictionary *value;
    if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        id array = dictionary;
        value = array[0];
    } else if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        value = dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell more about the crash? Are you sure `dictionary` is always a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` and never some other class or `nil`? Is `value` allowed to be `nil`? Can `dictionary` be an empty array? ARC?

Comment: Yes its always `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. `dictionary` is the results of an api call so I suppose theres a chance it can be nil or empty. The only place I can see a crash occurring is where cool_jb noted- when trying to access object from array that can be nil, or empty via subscript. Right?

Comment: I don't know without a backtrace and more code.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be that when you are trying to fetch the 0th index from array, and it may not exist, since there can be no elements in the array. Before extracting you can check this as

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
 value = array[0]
}
```

or you can directly use array.first, which is a safe method and won't crash even if the array is empty

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think this is probably where the crash is happening. I will use `array.first` to be safer.

Comment: @AnonProgrammer You are welcome :) Also let us know if this have worked for you after going through your analytics data